# Azure Function - localhost works but upstream fails with internal server error

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have the following health check / status method in my Azure function app:  (v4)

```
public static class HealthStatus
{
    [FunctionName("HealthStatus")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "health/status")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string qn = req.Query["qn"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        qn = qn ?? data?.name;

        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(qn )
            ? "qn : All. Status OK"
            : $"qn : {qn }. Status OK";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

Locally when I run a GET on this, i get the "All.  Status OK" method.
Upstream, after I publish to azure, when i use the "code & test" option in azure to try to run this function, it only works if I GET with a query string parameter called qn.  Otherwise, instead of a 200 OK, I get a "500 internal server error".
The logs show this error:

```
 2022-06-14T17:49:36.042 [Information] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2022-06-14T17:49:36.150 [Error] Executed 'HealthStatus' (Failed, Id=asdf-e859-asdf-asdf-asdf123123, Duration=78ms)'string' does not contain a definition for 'name'
```

Any tips as to why the results are different and how I can fix would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you call it with the qn query parameter, this line returns a value:

```
  string qn = req.Query["qn"];
```

Then this line, uses the value in qn:

```
 qn = qn ?? data?.name;
```

When you do not call with qn, it uses `data?.name`

data comes from the request body and does not have a property `name`

Comment: ok but locally when I run it i just do a get with no query string and no body... and it just works.

Comment: It may be that the contents of req.body is different depending on how it is tested